# ROUGE-1.5.1.pl problem when train seq2seq model

Tags: python, nlp, seq2seq, rouge

It is a problem about seq2seq-summarizer. ( [more details see](https://github.com/ymfa/seq2seq-summarizer))I run these codes on Google colab. I just train it one epoch,and it returns an error.
[the imformation about the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qi5Z3.png)

and I download ROUGE-1.5.5.pl from network and I just put this file under the folder without doing anything. I do not know if it works.
just like this:(also in ./data, there is the same file)
[how my files display in catalogue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBJZ9.png)
by doing this, the 'NOT FOUND" problem disappeared, but it have the new problem----"/bin/sh: 1: ./ROUGE-1.5.5.pl: Permission denied".

the error is in ./utils.py line 395
`

```
# run ROUGE
out = subprocess.check_output('./ROUGE-1.5.5.pl -e data -a -n 2 -2 4 -u ' + config_path,
                              shell=True, cwd=os.path.join(this_dir, 'data'))
```

`

I want to know how to solve it when run these codes on google colab.
and if you know more about if there is some way to change the implementation to make it be trained quicker. I did not modify any parameter, I just run "python train.py". And it takes me around 1 hour to train one epoch.

I would appreciate it if some one could help me whith the ROUGE-1.5.1.pl problem.